# Error when creating a navigate function through button click using router Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I am new to angular 6 and it's navigation/routing, I am sorry if this sounds obvious.

I am trying to have a button with a function to navigate to the login page, but I keep getting this error:

" Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError "

my html is :

```
<button ion-button (click) = "openLogin()" >Efetuar login</button>
```

my router is :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    outlet: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I've been researching on the matter and as long as the path corresponds to the path defined in the router there shouldn't be any issue but I keep getting this error.

Comment: forgot to show my  class with the function openLogin(), here it is :import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-balances',
  templateUrl: 'balances.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['balances.page.scss']
})
export class BalancesPage {
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){


}
  openLogin(): void {
    alert("login");this.router.navigate(['./login']); }}

Comment: are you having ./login as the path in router.navigate?

Comment: I don't like the "." in navigate(["./login"], try navigate(["/login"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named `router-outlet` is quite different than normal `router-outlet`.

This is how named `router-outlet` works

1.Add `outlet` to your route object as you are already doing now

```
{
    path: 'login',
    outlet: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
```

2.Add a name attribute to `router-outlet` tag

```
 <router-outlet name="login"></router-outlet>
```

3.Using `router.navigate`

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { login: [ 'login' ] }}]);
```

4.Using `routerLink`

```
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { login: ['login'] } }]"
```

I would recommend you to read this [post](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-named-router-outlet-popup-example) aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this in your imports this way:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true});
```

instead of:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```